# Uploading text files in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a `form.py` including `Floatfield` and `Charfield`. Now I want to add a new `Filefield` to upload a text file. But I fail.
The float var is submitted successfully and I could see they are changed with the change of the input, but I cannot find the file in located folders.

And also, how could I check whether file extensions are correct? Should I achieve it in view or model?

Could someone help me? I truly struggled with it.

model.py

```
file = models.FileField(upload_to='/Folder', null = True)
```

form.py

```
file = forms.FileField(label='data', required=False)
```

view.py is followed the structure in [Django official document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/file-uploads/).

```
def handle_uploaded_file(f):
with open('./test_temp_file.txt', 'wb+') as destination:
    for chunk in f.chunks():
        destination.write(chunk)


def file_upload(request):  
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = input_form(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])
            name = request.FILES['filename'].name
            time =  cleaned_data(timezone.now())
            form = {
                'name' : name,
                'time' : time
            }
        return render(request, 'home/results.html',{'form':form})
    else:  
        form = input_form()
        return render(request, 'home/input.html', {'form': form})
```

------Uploaded:
`HTML page` is like this:

```
<form method = "POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="temp_data_upload">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form_upload.temp_data.errors }}
{{ form_upload.temp_data }}
{% endif%}
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should `save` your `form` and refactor the code.

```
def file_upload(request):  
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = input_form(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])
            name = request.FILES['filename'].name
            time =  cleaned_data(timezone.now())
            form = {
                'name' : name,
                'time' : time
            }
            form.save() # <-- save your form
            return render(request, 'home/results.html',{'form':form})
    else:  
        form = input_form()
    return render(request, 'home/input.html', {'form': form})
```

**EDIT**
Make sure your `forms` contain the correct values.

```
 <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Thank you, however, it still fails. I want to say the `FileField` is a part of a big `form.py`. I double check the database, the other numbers are transferred perfectly, but the file variable is empty. Now it returns `MultiValueDictKeyError`, and I try to print `request.FILES`, it shows an empty dict. I'm truly confusde.

Comment: Check updated solution

Comment: I truly thank you for helping, however, I'm sure I add the `enctype` at the first time. I create a new `model` and `modelform` to collect upload file alone, and it looks better. The webpage will return `error` saying the file is required, instead of remindering me `temp_data` is not defined. So I believe the problems is in `html`. The `html` page could be seen in the edited question section.

Comment: Thank you so much. As I mentioned before, when I'm sure that the bug is related to `HTML` page, I check all lines and find that the upload HTML page will be imported to a general HTML page and the form is the general HTML page doesn't have `enctype` properties.  The project is cooperated with others and his part is not related to upload file so he didn't add it. It really takes me a lot of time. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Ask if you have some other question.